# Inheritance of final class from the Java internals perspective

Tags: java

While declaring a class as final , we cannot Inheritance this class , my question is why ? - from the java internals perspective.

I assume that the same principle apply to methods and instance as well.
is it somehow related to the class loader as well ? who is actually stopping me from override it?

Comment: that was not my question at all , my question was what is happening in the internals while declaring a final class/method/variable, who is stopping you from overriding it ?

Comment: This is a question about the Java language definition and rationale for why the language has a particular characteristic. This forum is used primarily for application of a language, not a meta discussion of the language definition. You need to find another place for such a discussion in order to get satisfactory answers or comments.

Comment: @ErstwhileIII is there any other place which i need to post it?

Comment: By the way -- a language that has particular characteristics will be implemented to adhere to those characteristics ... the characteristics do not come from an implementation, the implementation comes from the characteristics.

Comment: @ErstwhileIII understood , this is why i asked it , just to understand what really happening "underground" while declaring it

Comment: You are asking how the Java compiler determines that this language violation is a violation?! You still appear to be asking, whether you realize it or not, a meta-question about the semantics implied by declaring a "final" class and why you cannot create a sub-class of something that is final (i.e. cannot be subclassed).

Comment: Yes , that was my question.
I don't see any problem with it.

Just want to understand .. thats all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at it elementally, When you declare a variable as final, you did that because you don't want the value of that variable be changed  for any reason afterwards, Right?.

Okay, under the assumption that you agree to that. The same principle is also applicable to classes.

Let's look at it this way: Why will you ever want to inherit a class? Probably because you want get access to the properties of the class and her behaviors (methods), Right?  Once you have inherited these properties and behaviors you have the right the modify the accessible behavior to suite your precise need without having to re-implement all other behaviors. This is the value and power of in inheritance.

Hence, declaring a class as final implies that you don't want anyone to modify any behavior of the class. You tries to state that who so ever that will want use your class should use it as IS.

Therefore, any attempt to modify a final class is illogical and should be considered as error.

Eg. 
Imaging if someone should be able to inherit your final Authentication class and modifying the actual authentication behavior (method). This should be a security bridge as it might compromise your reasons for setting the class as final.

Hence, it is a design practice.

I hope that make some sense?

Answer (score 2):

It is nothing to do with Java internals.

The *purpose* of declaring a class to be `final` it to prevent it from being subclassed.

---

> My question was what happening "underground" while declaring final ...

Well ... when a class is declared as `final` a flag is set in the class file to say this.  If you then attempt to load a class that *purports* to be a subclass of a `final` class, the classloader will throw a `VerifyError` exception.  The checks are done in the `ClassLoader.defineClass(...)` methods ... which are also `final`, so that normal programs can't interfere with them.

This aspect of classfile verification needs to be watertight for Java security reasons.  If it wasn't then you could probably cause mayhem in a Java security sandbox by tricking trusted code into using (say) a mutable subtype of `String`.

The Java compiler also checks that you don't extend a `final` class, but you could subvert that by (for example) creating ".class" files by hand.  Hence the need for load-time checks ...

> Who is actually stopping me from override it?

Actually, it is the classloader.  See above.

Comment: My question was what happening "underground" while declaring final , i know that this is what it is meant to do..

Comment: compiler prevent and generate compile time error if try to declare subclass of final class

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder is there anything related to the class loader in that case? 
like when declaring on a static methods / variables that the class loader is creating them before creating an instance of the same class?

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder - Actually, the checking that really matters is done at load time by verification code deep within the JVM.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing related to the JVM or internals (not really sure what exaclty you mean by that), it's a compile issue simply because you're breaking the rules.

If I think myself as a Java compiler, after parsing the tokens in your code I'm just going to look around for logical errors (semantic analysis) e.g. a circular inheritance scheme. *The moment I see someone's attempt at extending a `final` class, I'm gonna go bazooka. That's it.* No need to wake up the big bosses, the JVM or any other internals because the program cannot be correctly compiled in the first place.

If you want to know how the compiler works the way it does *internally*, think that while the compiler parses your code, it creates and fills some structures internal to itself for the purpose of error-checking and bytecode-translation. Also imagine in a simplified scenario that the `final` keyword attached to a class just sets a field in one of these structures attached to your class. After syntactic analysis, the compiler goes on with "logical" (semantic) analysis and checks (among other things) if some lunatic tries extending a `final` class. Even a brute search in an inheritance graph can pull that off. If a class is final and still has children, halt and notify the lunatic. The issue won't get more internal than the compiler.